# Method to the lowest letter (in alphabetical order) in a string

Tags: java, string, if-statement, recursion, methods

I am trying to write a simple method that takes a String and returns the smallest letter of that String. For example, given the String "basic", "a" should be returned.

Here's the code that I've come up with. Currently I am getting an OutOfMemoryError. You will also notice that I've attempted to use recursion, but I am also open to suggestions that do not use recursion.

```
public static String smallestLetter(String str) {
        if (str.length() == 1)
            return str.substring(0);
        else if (str.charAt(0) < str.charAt(1))
            return smallestLetter(str.substring(0) + str.substring(2,str.length()));
        else
            return smallestLetter(str.substring(1,str.length()));
}
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong and what I can do to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Why use recursion for this? Just iterate and keep a reference to the min.

Comment: You need to read the javadoc of substring. `substring(0)` does not do what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
        return smallestLetter(str.substring(0) + str.substring(2,str.length()));
```

`str.substring(0)` is actually the entire string; so in this line, the method re-calls itself with a string that's almost twice as big as the original. Just a few method-calls in, you can already have a massive string that's bigger than you can allocate.

The minimal fix is:

```
        return smallestLetter(str.charAt(0) + str.substring(2,str.length()));
```

but a better fix is to use iteration rather than recursion:

```
public static String smallestLetter(String str) {
    char ret = str.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); ++i)
        if (str.charAt(i) < ret)
            ret = str.charAt(i);
    return String.valueOf(ret);
}
```

**Edited to add:** Note that, as [Alexey Malev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2667872/alexey-malev) points out below, this will raise an exception if `str` is the empty string (`""`). In addition, it does not do any filtering to specifically identify *letters*; rather, it will return the least *character* in the string, whether or not that's a letter.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (str.charAt(i) < ret)` ?

Comment: @GoldRoger: Should be, and now is. Thanks! :-)

Comment: The code returns first letter, which may cause OutOfBounds for zero-length string. Another problem - string may contain no letters, in that case you'll return first character which might be not the desired result.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev: Re: first problem: correct. This method *will* throw an exception for a zero-length string. That was also true of the OP's code, so I assumed it was acceptable behavior. Re: second problem: This code does not make any attempt to filter by actual "letters", because the OP's code does not, and I'm not sure whether it's really supposed to. (OP may have meant "characters", or may simply not care about the behavior for strings that contain non-letters.)

Comment: @ruakh Your statement perfectly makes sense, I wrote it just for OP awareness of these.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev: Ah, fair enough. I've now edited my answer to incorporate those points.

Answer (score 1):

I think you code goes too deep into recursion and at some moment the heap memory is over.

If we assume that you need to find only Latin letters, I'd do it like that:

```
public static String smallestLetter(String str) {
    for (Character ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch) {
        if (str.contains(String.valueOf(ch))) {
            return String.valueOf(ch);
        }
    }
    return "No characters in the string :(";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char min = s.charAt(0);
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && s.charAt(i) < min)
        min = s.charAt(i);
return min;
```